# Generating Dynamic CSS with PHP and HTML 5 Preloader

Tags: php, css

I am trying to get rid of static CSS files for my web site; the reason behind, CSS is just static. To empower it with super powers of PHP, I am creating a stack of all CSS styles right in my PHP code; finally, just before the </body>; I'll combine all CSS and write into a CSS file and include. It would look like:

```
<body>

.. markup ..

<?php $css->add('.header'       ,'background:#ccc'); ?>
<?php $css->add('.sidebar ul'   ,'margin:0'); ?>

.. other markup and more $css->add()s. ..

<?php $css->generate(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

It will output something like:

```
<html>
<body>
    ... markup ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="generated.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
</body>
</html>
```

Page layout will appear entirely un-styled until CSS loads. What other disadvantages of this approach can be? Will it be practical?

Comment: I could be wrong, as I haven't tested this, but I think including a CSS link outside of the head is going to cause your page to load twice, once without style and then again with style when it sees the stylesheet linked at the bottom... why not just use JavaScript?

Comment: I personally would suggest against this. `.header` should be one style, while eg `.header-alert` would be another. You should change the class of the element rather than dynamically creating the css file, which would not help in caching or various other web programming components. Yes it's static, but you can control what you want by changing class, and when someone else maintains your code eg, they'll know what's going rather than figure out your nifty idea. And what happens if someone with no php experience is asked to change some font. My 2 cents